# Media queries based on height

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a site which contains a header image that I want to fit 70% of the screen height on all screens and on the remaining space I want to print some text.

Should I use javascript or should I use media-queries?

Where can I find the standard **height** parameters for which I have to write the media queries? I found the standard resolutions based on **width** [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Comment: Save yourself some headaches and use Javascript.  It's absolutely the easiest and most reliable way to set dynamic heights.

Comment: Save even more headaches and don't bother trying to figure out how to set something to a percentage of the height of the viewport.

Comment: If you want it to be 70% percent of the height of all screens, why not just use css? #header{ height:70%; }

Comment: @jdu won't the use of javascript affect my Google Search Ranking? I've heard it should be avoided

Comment: @OleHaugset that's the height of the page--not the screen.

Comment: also note that the height of a viewport can be come very tiny. For instance, your iphone in landscape mode with the keyboard open.

Comment: @HelloLili this kind of JS won't affect your search ranking.

Comment: What about `vh`, guys? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `vh` that will work for you. 1vh equals to 1% of browsers viewport. So if you set `header{height:70vh;}` it will use 70% of what user can see.

**Additional relative lengths:**
There are more relative lengths than just `vh`. There is:

- `vh` - Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport
- `vw` - Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport
- `vmin` - Relative to 1% of viewport's smaller dimension
- `vmax` - Relative to 1% of viewport's larger dimension

These lengths are supported by all browsers, https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units.

**source**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: This is a good idea. I'm surprised at how much browser support it actually has: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units